# Passing variable from controller in components/blade

Tags: php, laravel

i have this situation.

```
Undefined variable: city (View: \newjoblist\resources\views\components\hero.blade.php)
```

in my controller i have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\City;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CitiesController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index(Request $request){

        $city = City::orderBy('name') // variable displayed in view
        ->get();
        

        // return view('components.hero')->with('city',$city);
        $this->view('<components.hero')->with('city', $this->city);

    }
}
```

and in components/hero.blade.php

```
<select class="form-group" id="s" name="s">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        @foreach ($city as $cities)
                        <option value="{{$cities}}">{{$cities->name}}</option>
                       
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
```

i don't know if i need to do something in web.php

Comment: why you are commenting this line `// return view('components.hero')->with('city',$city);` ?

Comment: bcoz i try different methods to get results.

Comment: Okay, please check the mentioned answer, and let us know the attempt result

Answer (score 2):

you need to update your index method to

```
public function index(Request $request){

        $cities = City::orderBy('name') // variable displayed in view
        ->get();
        

         return view('components.hero')->with('cities',$cities);

    }
```

and at the view

```
<select class="form-group" id="s" name="s">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        @foreach ($cities as $city)
                        <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->name}}</option>
                       
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
```

Comment: I tried, but in vain, the same error

Comment: are you using it at any other line in this view ?
the mentioned snippet shouldn't show the same `$city` error, find on the view at other lines

Comment: ```Undefined variable: cities (View``` I'm not using, is the same error at the same line in view. ```cities```appear because I followed your advice, and I reversed the names of the values

Comment: i have no idea why its still not accissible at the view
,lets try another way of passing data to view for double check , 
please try this 
`return view('components.hero', compact('cities'));`
or this 
`return view('components.hero', ['cities'=>$cities]);`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   $cities = City::orderBy('name') // variable displayed in view
   ->get();
   return view('components.hero', compact('cities'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass in your code city as class membervariable but previously you assign only to $city.

Change this line: `$this->view('<components.hero')->with('city', $this->city);` to `view('components.hero')->with('city',$city);` . What you already had a line above ;-)

You can also pass Vars to your blade like that:

```php
view('components.hero', ['city' => $city];
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the comment i find out that you are trying another way to get the data.
So you can do it like this.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\City;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CitiesController extends Controller
{
    private $city;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->city = new City();
    }

    public function index(Request $request) {

        $cities = $this->city->query()->orderBy('name')->get();

        return view('<components.hero')->with('cities', $cities);
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```blade
<select class="form-group" id="s" name="s">
     <option value=""></option>
     @foreach ($cities as $city)
     <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to continue the error because I want to display in components.hero where is another controller? this is my web.php....

`Route::get('/', [Controllers\ListingController::class, 'index']) ->name('listings.index');`
and i have others views in this controller

**UPDATE***

if I use diff. the route in web.php it's works

```
Route::get('/search', [Controllers\CitiesController::class, 'index']);
```

-> displaying cities from DB